# Sizing of 1600' water pipe run

Tags: water, pipe

I'm looking at running water to a water trough that is 1600' away from my water source.  I'll need about 5-10 gpm flow at the trough.  My water source produces 40-60 psi from a bladder tank and has a 3/4" port.  I am hoping to run a 3/4" PVC all the way but am concerned about flow loss from psi loss?

Comment: Holy cow!  How far up or down hill is this trough from the source?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Home Improvement.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I disagree. Just because you don't have water trough at your home, doesn't mean others don't.

Comment: Looks like a DIY home project to me. What is the change in elevation is the trough higher, lower or at the same level. I voted to keep it open.

Comment: Ed and Tester, I'm fine with your choice, but I'll ask: if I have a computer in my house, does that make debugging my computer a valid question for SE Home Improvement? In other words, are questions where the subject merely may be close to a house considered Home Improvement? (If there's a meta question addressing this, pointers would be welcome.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom It's a plumbing question, which are on topic here. The OP is not asking about the trough, they're asking about getting water to it.  Answers to this could be useful for sizing pipe of various lengths for various applications.  If the OP was asking about sizing wire to a receptacle for a trough heater, would that be off topic?

Comment: So, a plastering job on the [ISS](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/main/) would be on-topic, as the techniques needed are directly related to home improvement (excepting the zero-gee difficulties). Works for me, and thanks.

Comment: I've asked about the on topicness of this question on [Meta](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/1261/33), if anybody is interested.

Comment: Whats the fixation with the water trough? If he had just stated that he was running water to an outbuilding 1600' away, would you still have a problem with it @DanielGriscom ??

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer, but if I were you I would run 1" 160-psi-rated black poly pipe, simply because you can buy it in giant spools and it's cheaper than PVC, it also handles freezing better than PVC (which just bursts). You'll have a lot less connections to make which means less chance of leaks.

Comment: BTW, I was being serious, not snide, when I said "works for me, and thanks." I'm not sure what I could have done to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise!  There is a 15' drop over the 1600' run so gravity should definitely help here.  I'll look into the poly pipe and post what ever I end up doing.  PS: I'm on a ranch and very remote so DIY projects are the norm around here ... can't even find contractors to do small projects in remote areas.

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;dr**

To get 5 gpm, you need a [pressure head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_head) of about 85 ft. (i.e your inlet would have to be 85 ft above your outlet).  Of course, this is what they make pumps for!  To get 85 ft of pressure head, you need about a ~0.15-hp pump.

**Detailed Answer**
Someone should definitely check my math on this :P

**Assumptions and constraints:**

1. No rise or drop in pipe (i.e. you're pumping across flat ground)
2. Minor losses (e.g. through unions, etc.) are negligible given the large length-to-diameter ratio of the tubing run.
3. ID of 3/4" PVC: 0.824 in or 68.7E-3 ft (based on OD nominal of 1.050 in and wall thickness nominal of 0.113 in)
4. Equivalent roughness (ε) of PVC pipe: 0.000005 ft (ref. Moody & Colebrook)
5. Density of water (ρ) at 60 °F: 1.94 slugs/ft<sup>3</sup>
6. Dynamic viscosity (μ) of water at 60 °F: 2.34E-5 lb-s/ft<sup>2</sup>

**Solution:**

Because the diameter is constant over the length of the pipe, inlet and outlet *velocities* are the same.  We can assume pressures at the inlet and outlet are the same, too (large, open tanks).  So if we modify the Bernoulli equation with p<sub>1</sub>=p<sub>2</sub>=V<sub>1</sub>=V<sub>2</sub>=0, we get:

h<sub>p</sub> = (*f* * l * V<sup>2</sup>) / (D * 2g )

where h<sub>p</sub> is the head pressure required to make the flow, *f* is the friction factor of the pipe, l is the length, V is the linear flow velocity, D is the diameter (ID), and g is acceleration due to gravity.

We find V by:

V = Q/A

where Q is the flow rate and A is the area of the pipe.  Q is 5 gpm, or 11.14E-3 ft<sup>3</sup>/s (60 seconds in a minute, and 7.48 gallons per ft<sup>3</sup>).  The area of a circle is π * (D/2)<sup>2</sup>, so our area is 3.71E-3 ft<sup>2</sup>.  Thus, our velocity is 3.01 ft/s.

To find *f*, we need to know the ratio of equivalent roughness to diameter (ε/D) and the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number). ε/D is 72.8E-6.  We find the Reynolds number, Re, using the equation

Re = (ρ * V * D) / μ

Thus, Re for our flow is 17.14E3.  With Re and ε/D known, we determine *f* from the [Moody Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moody_chart). *f* is approximately 0.0258.

Solving our original equation above for h<sub>p</sub> gives us h<sub>p</sub> = 84.5 ft

To find h<sub>p</sub> in terms of power, P<sub>hp</sub>, we use the equation

P<sub>hp</sub> = ρ * g * Q * h<sub>p</sub>

which yields P<sub>hp</sub> of 58.8 ft-lbf/s. Converted to horsepower, this is 0.106 hp.